# AngularJS Expressions in html tag

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to use AngularJS Expressions in tag as below

```
class="({{product.id}} > 2) ? 'act':''"
```

after execution which can be this

```
class="( 5 > 2) ? 'act':' ' "
```

will it be possible that it cloud be like

```
class='act'
```

if yes then how ?
I have tried above code but not getting

> class='act'

same for ng-hide

Comment: Take a look at [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help someone

> replace class to ng-class

as below

> ng-class="{'act': product.id > 2}"
>
> replace ng-hide to ng-if

as below

> ng-if="selectedItem == product.pageID"

so you can skip records

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-class instead of class :

```
ng-class="{'act': product.id > 2}"
```

Have a look at the doc for more samples :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: for ng-hide="{'false': selectedItem ==  product.id}"  not working

Comment: the string 'false' is truthy.

Comment: `ng-hide="selectedItem != product.is"` would be the correct answer. But in this case, ask a new question, or have a look at previous questions.

Comment: thank you sir for your reply
i have manage this by using ng-if instead ng-hide and thats work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-class attribute:
ng-class="{'act': product.id > 2}"

That should work for you.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

Check this one may help you :

```css
.one{
  color:red; 
 }

.two{
  color:blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app ng-init="num=2">
 
  <p ng-class="{'two': num==2}">Hello</p>
  
</div>
```